# Upgrading from apache-tomcat-8.0.30. to 8.5.35. is causing 403 responses to some POST requests to our API

Tags: api, tomcat, tomcat8, http-status-code-403

We're running on a pretty outdated version of tomcat at the moment, 8.0.30. We tried to update to version 8.5.35, but we're running into a ton of trouble. Basically MOST of the requests to our REST API work, but some POST requests are returning 403 responses, but we're not sure why.

We eventually had to give up and go back to 8.0.30. for the time being, because we just couldn't figure out what was different in the newer version that would be restricting these calls. We looked in the web.xml and basically every other config file we can think of, but there's no indication of any restrictions, limits, constraints, nothing. Everything else except those 2 POST requests that we identified works, including several other POST requests.

Is there anything about the newer version that could explain why this would be? Downgrading to 8.0.30. is literally the only thing we needed to do to get it working again, everything else is the same.

Comment: Do you have an example of the POST request that is failing?

Comment: POST /services/availability

Sadly I don't have access to the code to see exactly what it's doing, but basically it returns the text "All host services accessible from api.*.*" after it checks to make sure critical services are available. On apache 8.5.35 it just returns 403.